# Why does JSDocs (in VS code) ignore the @returns directive when calling another function to initialize a variable?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Consider this sample:

```js
const functionGetter = () => () => { return false; };

/**
 * @function
 * @returns {string}
 */
const fn = functionGetter();
```

One can tell that the JS docs I've written over `fn` is a complete fabrication. The function will return a boolean not a string. However I would expect JS docs to faithfully list my overriding declaration that this is indeed a function that returns a string.

Instead JS Docs shows these two declarations:

```js
const functionGetter: () => () => boolean;
const fn: () => boolean;
```

Is there something wrong with my JS docs or is it just willfully ignoring it because it knows better?

Interestingly prepending this JS docs above `functionGetter` results in fn showing what I'd expect:

```js
/**
 * @function functionGetter
 * @returns {function(): string}
 */
```

This results in the following two JS docs declarations:

```js
const functionGetter: () => () => string;
const fn: () => string;
```

So how can I get JS docs to stop ignoring the declaration directly on fn. I want to change fn's declaration without affecting functionGetter.